# database error schema.rb is not generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked at some other answers about this and none worked.  I am migrating my database and schema.rb is not being generated. I have tried rake db:migrate:reset, rake db:drop db:create db:schema:dump db:schema:load db:migrate, and none produce the schema.rb file which I had a problem with for a while.  I also ran rake db:rollback and then rake db:migrate:reset but it still throws a duplicate table error, even after I deleted schema.rb, so I don't know what it is using without schema.rb but the error is obviously the same, and using the same old schema. I originally thought it was the database because it was throwing a duplicate table error but found out the schema.rb file was old and out of sync with my migrations.  I also have thought restarting the server but am not sure if that will make a differences, also it seems it stops and restarts anyway once I restart my laptop.

schema.rb is not updating/generating in sync with migrations

EDIT: development.log entry

```
    ^[[1m^[[35m (1.8ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[35mCREATE TABLE   "categories" ("id" bigserial primary key, "title" character varying, "created_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL)^[[0m

  ^[[1m^[[36mTRANSACTION (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[31mROLLBACK^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35m (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT pg_advisory_unlock(6149806219574577000)^[[0m
```

I assume its pg_advisory_unlock which I am going to look into

Comment: The schema.rb file is created by using the database adapter specific methods for dumping the database and parsing the resulting SQL. Deleting the schema.rb file to fix a problem makes no sense at all since it should be the source of truth for what your database looks like and should be checked into version control. Your migrations should just be transformations of the schema. Not its definition.

Comment: Also make sure that you're actually looking at the right file. If `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` is set Rails will output `structure.sql` instead of the ruby schema.

Answer (score 1):

> `db:migrate:reset` but it still throws a duplicate table error, even after I deleted schema.rb, so I don't know what it is using without schema.rb

Well the `db:migrate:reset` is just a drop/create/migrate, so it's getting its information from the migrations, not `schema.rb`

Based on the error you've kind of mentioned you're getting, it seems like you have a migration that's trying to create a table that already exists in your DB.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, I am looking into the schema_migrations record and how that is stored in the database, I am wondering if the schema_migrations table is storing old migrations and trying to run them again.  That is all I have found out is that schema_migrations table records migration history, and I am thinking I can just find that and clear it out.

Comment: I have changed application.rb with config.active_record.schema_format = :sql but still the same error, I cannot figure out where I have any duplication.  When I check that database and tables, it has all the tables in my migration, so even though the migrations are canceled and an error is thrown on the first table in the migration, all the tables are created in the database...?

Comment: If you clear out that table then Rails will try to re-run all your migrations, which will definitely cause problems. You should update your question to include the actual details of your error.